# Cannot call coInvoke function from RecursiveAction class

Tags: java, jdk1.7

I have written a simple code to run in parallel using the Java fork join functionality.

I am using Java version 7 (JDK 1.7)

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class forkedPotential extends RecursiveAction {

    public forkedPotential(double rmin,double rmax,double rstep){

        for (double rad = rmin; rad <= rmax; rad = rad + rstep){
           double V = rad*rad;
           System.out.println(rad+" "+V);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        forkedPotential first = new forkedPotential(0.01,1.0,0.1);
        forkedPotential second = new forkedPotential(1.01,2.0,0.1);
        forkedPotential third = new forkedPotential(2.01,3.0,0.1);
        forkedPotential fourth = new forkedPotential(3.01,4.0,0.1);
        forkedPotential fifth = new forkedPotential(4.01,5.0,0.1);
        coInvoke(new forkedPotential(0.01,1.0,0.1),new forkedPotential(1.01,2.0,0.1));
    }

}
```

I have a problem however that coInvoke cannot be called.

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol: method coInvoke(forkedPotential,forkedPotential)
  location: class forkedPotential
----
```

This should be an acceptable use as forkedPotential extends RecursiveAction.
And Alt-Return does not give me any helpful guidance.

I have tried other utilisations of coInvoke such as

```
        forkedPotential[] tasks = {first,second,third,fourth,fifth};
        coInvoke(tasks);
```

but with no joy.

I do not know why this coInvoke function cannot be found as is is a function in RecursiveAction.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by substituting

```
        coInvoke(tasks);
```

With

```
        RecursiveAction.invokeAll(tasks);
```